# Azure: Is there a way to cache/reuse files downloaded from Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a file upload/download service that uploads files to Blob storage. I have another service (a job service) that needs to download files from file service (using the blob storage URLs) and process those files. The files are read-only (they are not going to change during their lifetime). In many cases, the same file can be used in different jobs. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to download a file once and all the instances of my job service use that downloaded file. So can I store the downloaded file in some shared location and access it from all the instances of my service? Does it even make sense to do it this way? Would the cost of fetching the file from blob be the same as reading it from a shared location (if that is even possible)?

Comment: Lots of ways to cache content (local instance disk, cache service if the content isn't too large, etc). You'd need to measure performance, choose a way to manage cached content, manage situations when source content changes, etc. There's really no right answer to this though.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time David. In my case the files are going to be large (hundreds of MB). This is why I am trying to figure out if I can reuse a file that is downloaded from blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

Azure also provide a file storage. Azure file storage provide a facility to mount that storage as a drive and access contain of azure file storage. 
Buy for this you need to download it once and then upload to file storage.
Then you can mount that to any instance of virtual machine or local drive.
That is a alternate way to achieve your goal.
Check this

http://www.ntweekly.com/?p=10034